# Calculating position on an arc

Tags: geometry

If the length of `a`, `b` and `d` is known - how can I calculate the angle `α`? 
[image: Path]

Please keep in mind that I'm not a professional     mathematician. I know how to calculate the sides and angles within a triangle but that's about it.

Comment: Nice illustration!

Comment: @MvG I used [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org) to draw it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd prefer the radius $r=d/2$ over the diameter. I imagine a coordinate system in the center of the circle, with $x$ axis pointing left and $y$ axis pointing down. Then the point where arc and line intersect has coordinates $x=r\cos\alpha$ and $y=r\sin\alpha$. The length $b$ is $\sqrt{(a + y)^2 + (r-x)^2}$ due to Pythagoras' theorem. So you have

\begin{align*}
b^2 &= (a+y)^2+(r-x)^2 = (a^2 + 2ay + y^2) + (r^2 - 2rx + x^2) \\
b^2 &= a^2 + 2ay + r^2 - 2rx + (x^2+y^2) = a^2 + 2ay - 2rx + 2r^2 \\
2rx - 2ay &= a^2-b^2+2r^2
\end{align*}

That's the equation of a line, and a line intersects a circle in two points. So you have to expect two possible solutions. If you want to find them, I suggest you first find two points on your line, by setting $x=0$ resp. $y=0$.

\begin{align*}
x_1 &= 0 \qquad \implies & y_1 &= \frac{a^2-b^2+2r^2}{-2a} \\
y_2 &= 0 \qquad \implies & x_2 &= \frac{a^2-b^2+2r^2}{2r}
\end{align*}

Now you look for some point on the line, i.e. with coordinates

\begin{align*}
x &= x_1 + \lambda(x_2-x_1) = (1-\lambda)x_1 + \lambda x_2 \\
y &= y_1 + \lambda(y_2-y_1) = (1-\lambda)y_1 + \lambda y_2
\end{align*}

which also satisfies $x^2+y^2=r^2$. So you have

\begin{align*}
r^2 &= \bigl(x_1 + \lambda(x_2-x_1)\bigr)^2 + \bigl(y_1 + \lambda(y_2-y_1)\bigr)^2 \\
&= \bigl(x_1^2+y_1^2\bigr) + 2\bigl(x_1(x_2-x_1)+y_1(y_2-y_1)\bigr)\lambda + \bigl((x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2\bigr)\lambda^2 \\
&= y_1^2 - 2y_1^2\lambda + \bigl(x_2^2+y_1^2\bigr)\lambda^2
\end{align*}

That's a quadratic equation in $\lambda$, which you solve using the [quadratic formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula). Then you have two possible values for $\lambda$, from which you compute $x$ and $y$, from which you conclude $\alpha$ using

$$\tan\alpha = \frac yx$$

but taking the proper quadrant into account, the way [atan2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) does.

## Example

Suppose you have $r=49,a=58,b=107$ as indicated in the comments. Then you get $y_1=\frac{3283}{116}$ and $x_2=-\frac{67}{2}$. This leads to the equation

$$\frac{25879085}{13456}\lambda^2-\frac{10778089}{6728}\lambda-\frac{21529767}{13456}=0$$

which you can simplify by multiplying everything with $13456$ so you get

$$25879085\lambda^2-21556178\lambda-21529767=0$$

You solve that using the quadratic formula

\begin{align*}
\lambda_{1,2}&=\frac{21556178\pm\sqrt{21556178^2+4\cdot25879085\cdot21529767}}{2\cdot25879085}
\\&=\frac{2401}{5765}\pm\frac{19894}{386255}\sqrt{379}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
\lambda&=\frac{2401}{5765}+\frac{19894}{386255}\sqrt{379} &
\lambda&=\frac{2401}{5765}-\frac{19894}{386255}\sqrt{379} \\
x &= -\frac{160867}{11530}-\frac{9947}{5765}\sqrt{379}\approx-47.5 &
x &= -\frac{160867}{11530}+\frac{9947}{5765}\sqrt{379}\approx19.6 \\
y &= \frac{95207}{5765}-\frac{16807}{11530}\sqrt{379}\approx-11.9 &
y &= \frac{95207}{5765}+\frac{16807}{11530}\sqrt{379}\approx44.9 \\
\tan\alpha &\approx 0.25 &
\tan\alpha &\approx 2.29 \\
\alpha &\approx 3.39 \approx 194° &
\alpha &\approx 1.16 \approx 66°
\end{align*}

[image: Example situation]

Comment: $\tan\alpha=\frac{y}{x}$ for all point of the circle.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. Unfortunately I'm unable to understand it. The thing that bothers me is that I'm even unable to figure out what you did using Pythagoras' theorem. In my desperation I measured the values of `a` (~ 58), `b` (~ 73), `r` (~ 49), `x` (~ 17) and `y` (~ 46) within my drawing. Then put those values into your first formula and let google calculate the result: sqrt((58 + 46)^2 + (49 - 17)^2) = ~109  

The result is not even near to the value I measured for `b` - so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Martin: I'd say $b$ in your drawing should be more like $110$ to be consistent with the other figures you gave. At least that's what I measure here.

Comment: Ignore my first comment: I did an error while measuring the value of `b` (~ 107). Now I still have to somehow understand the rest of your answer (I never even heard of quadratic equation before).

Comment: @Martin: I included an example computation, that might help you check your own computation.

Comment: @MvG Only after I saw your drawing I realised that I'm just looking for the intersecting points of two circles (Tausend Dank dafür!). I'm still unable to understand your formula but I'm at least able to use it. By googling "intersecting circles" I even found [a much simpler looking formula](http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/51836.html) - that I'm able to use but unable to understand aswell :D